# Issues getting the proper server session id when using jasny/sso over ajax

Tags: php, ajax, single-sign-on

As stated in the title, I'm currently trying to implement the Ajax version of [Jasny SSO](https://github.com/jasny/sso)

I got my SSO server setup in `a.com`, which also has a broker setup and I've got another broker in `b.com`

When using only browser redirect, I can see in the sso server logs

```
Broker request with session  {"broker":"brokerAName","token":"a","session":"a"}
Broker request with session  {"broker":"brokerBName","token":"b","session":"a"}
```

And everything is fine.

But when I do an ajax call for the attach from `b.com` , I see the following log in the SSO server

```
Broker request with session  {"broker":"brokerBName","token":"b","session":"c"}
```

So the issue here is that it has attached me to a different session ID (the `c` one) but I excpected it to attach to the `a` session

I followed the implementation of the [demo/ajax-broker](https://github.com/jasny/sso/tree/master/demo/ajax-broker) and I'm really wondering what I did wrong.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !